# PHP Failed to create COM object `Word.Application'

Tags: php, com

I have 3 environments

1 Test Server, 2 Production Server.

I have a form where the user can input information and then submit file(doc, docx, rtf) and the system will convert it into a pdf.

The code works well in the test server but both production server gives

```
Failed to create COM object `Word.Application': Server execution failed
```

- Microsoft Office 2010 is already installed.
- access permission is already set in dcomcnfg->my computer->properties->com security
- extension=php_com_dotnet.dll  is already added in php.ini

Code I am using:

```
function convert2pdf($path, $year, $savedName)
{
    $word = new COM("Word.Application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
      // set it to 1 to see the MS Word window (the actual opening of the document)
    $word->Visible = 0;
      // recommend to set to 0, disables alerts like "Do you want MS Word to be the default .. etc"
    $word->DisplayAlerts = 0;
    
    //open file
    $word->Documents->Open($path.$savedName);

    $word->ActiveDocument->ExportAsFixedFormat($path.$year.'\\'.substr_replace($savedName , 'pdf', strrpos($savedName , '.') +1), 17, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, false);
      // quit the Word process
    $word->Quit(false);
      // clean up
    unset($word);

    //delete temp file
    unlink($path.'\\'.$savedName);

    //return new file path
    return $year.'\\'.substr_replace($savedName , 'pdf', strrpos($savedName , '.') +1);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

## Updates as of Oct 6, 2015

It works on Test server, my laptop which runs on Windows 7 but does not work on the Production Server which runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: Sorry; you can't. You cannot run Word from a server environment such as PHP. It's a technical disaster waiting to happen and (depending on who your users are) it could be a violation of your Office license. Word is designed and tested to run in an interactive environment with a human at the console. It will really crash and burn unpredictably in a non-interactive service. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665967/2230) is one of the many, many SO answers that already covers this.

Comment: We do have licensed office and the main purpose of it just to convert doc, docx and rtf to pdf. It is weird though, it was working with my test environment and production but now no longer works on my production

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't know specifically why Word is not working in your particular case; I'm just letting you know that you are fighting a battle you can't ultimately win. If you must do this from a web server, there are 3rd party components that are designed for use in server environments that convert Word documents to PDF.

Comment: @EuroMicelli may I know what are thecomponents so that I can have a look on them?