# Quit method not killing WINWORD processes

Tags: c#, .net, com, ms-word, office-interop

I'm running into the classic scenario where, when creating Word COM objects in .NET (via the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly), the WinWord process won't exit even though I'm properly closing and releasing the objects.

Below is my code:

```
 // Quit Word and release the ApplicationClass object.
        if (oWordApp != null)
        {
            oWordApp.Quit(ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing);

            oWordApp = null;
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Any idea why I am having this problem?  I don't have this problem locally though.  Only on the production server.

Comment: Crystal ball says: "don't deploy the Debug build to a production server".

Comment: You **cannot** run Word from a server environment. Redesign your app using a different technology. This is a technical disaster waiting to happen and (depending on who your users are) it might be a violation of your Office license. Word is designed and tested to run in an interactive environment with a human at the console. It will really crash and burn unpredictably in a non-interactive service. See http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757. Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665967/2230) is one of the many, many SO answers that already covers this.

Answer (score -1):

COM object should be terminated by reducing reference count to make it zero.

`if (Marshal.IsComObject(oWordApp))
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWordApp);
}`

Normally the best place to locate such code is to use "Dispose" method by implementing IDisposable.