# Need MS Office installed to convert PPT to another format?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, com, 32bit-64bit

I'm exporting a PPT file into JPGs using the following code. It does a great job locally, but I'm not sure if it's because I have PowerPoint installed.

When I deploy to the server, I get all types of COM errors. I continue looking for solutions, but I'm thinking that it won't work because the server doesn't have PowerPoint installed.

So, will the following code only work if I have MS PowerPoint installed? Thanks.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application appPpt = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation objActivePresentation
        = appPpt.Presentations.Open(SourceFilePath,
                                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue,
                                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed,
                                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide objSlide in objActivePresentation.Slides)
    {
        objSlide.Export(DestinationFilePath + i + ".JPG", "JPG", 1024, 768);
        i++;
    }
    objActivePresentation.Close();
    appPpt.Quit();
```

Comment: it doesn't look like you are disposing of the COM Interop objects correctly
do a google search on `C# Marshal.ReleaseComObject`

Comment: I'll look into it, but this code works great locally. Are you saying that `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is the reason I get `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed` errors?

Comment: Of course you would need PowerPoint installed. But it doesn't matter. You cannot run Office applications from a service environment. Redesign your app using a different technology. This is a technical disaster waiting to happen. Office apps are designed and tested to run in an interactive environment with a human at the console. It can, and it will, crash and burn unpredictably in a non-interactive service. See http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757. Also, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665967/2230) is one of the many, many SO answers that already covers this.

Comment: do not rely on the good old fashion excuse of `Well it works on my machine Locally` perhaps you need to make sure that the objects are installed on the target machine in regards to the references..

Comment: @EuroMicelli,  I appreciate your concern, but you do not know where or how I'm using this code. The only relevant sentence in your comment is `Of course you would need PowerPoint installed`.

Comment: @MethodMan, what I wrote was meant as a comment, not an excuse. Please don't mix it up to get an upvote.

Comment: Usually when someone says "on a server", they mean "a service, or a web site". If your application is being installed on a server but is nevertheless an interactive application, then my comment doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need Microsoft Office installed on the machine running the code in order to use the Interop assemblies.

Some 3rd party libraries, such as Aspose.Slides do not require Office to be installed on the machine.