# Using COM, in PHP, to combine Word files

Tags: php, ms-word, com

I am trying to get information on combining Word files (both .DOC, and .DOCX) using COM from PHP.  I already have an installation of Word, the latest PHP version, and some basic information from PHP.net.

I have seen rough examples of doing this *without* COM through such methods as unzipping the embedded XML and making manipulations.  As far as I can tell, none of these methods are simple, or work very well.

I am hoping using COM is the solution that I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can do this quite simply with COM; far more simply than by unzipping the embedded XML. However, if you are running this PHP on a web server, each request will have to fire up a new (hidden) instance of Word. An alternative is the [Office Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), but I am not sure how to go about using it from PHP.

Comment: Sorry, but I beg to differ. You **cannot** use Word via COM from a web server app. Design your app using a different method. This is a technical disaster waiting to happen and (depending on who your users are) it *might* even be a violation of your Office license. Word is designed and tested to run in an interactive environment with a human at the console. It *will* crash and burn unpredictably in a non-interactive service. See http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757. Also, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665967/2230) is one of the many, many SO answers that already covers this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will consider a new solution, based on your responses and the link provided.