# need some info about microsoft.interop.excel

Tags: c#, excel

I want to generate excel file. That's why I am using Microsoft. Interop. excels library and my work has been done. But right now someone says Microsoft. Interop. excels library is not a good approach for web based projects. It is good for desktop based project. Is it true. If true, so why and what's the issue that approach not suitable for the web. And which is the better approach for generate excel file on web based project.

Comment: Multi-threading is one consideration. There are plenty of open source excel generators available.

Comment: This similar question might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663123/use-office-interop-on-asp-net-mvc6-website

Comment: This [microsoft support document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) describes the many technical issues with using interop for server-side automation. Note that there are also legal implications. It is a violation of the EULA to use server-side automation to allow multiple unlicensed users to access Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I have some experience with working with Excel files in both web and windows environments.

My answer to you is that it heavily depends:

Microsoft.Interop.Excel(Let's call it MIE) is cross calling Excel libraries itself to do it's job therefore it's more reliable in case of future versions and better upgradable. But it's not well formatted, there will be no intellisense and most important one you require Excel installed on the running machine.

So base on these info you need to answer these questions:

1- Are you gonna distribute your code or you are going to deploy it?

2- Do you have access to server or no?

3- Is it to create Excel or to read it or both?

4- Is it a project for a long run or a short lifetime one?

1) If you are going to distribute your code find a third party tool. Because if you use MIE you need to tell your customer to install Excel on their machine (which they might be unable to do because of the question 2) and also your code might break because of it's communication issues with MIE.

2) If you don't have access to server (i.e. a hosting deployment environment or your server is managed by your company), you can't install excel on it so let's select a third party tool, compiled in your code.

3) If you want to read excel and you answered the previous questions go for MIE it's a must since most third party tools aren't really good and reliable for opening files. They are mostly able to create ones. Unless you want to create files then you want to use the same files later. Usually third party tools are great in opening files created themselves.

4) If it's gonna work a long time it's better to use MIE because it's essentially better to maintain. Microsoft uses this MIE in their products like Dynamics CRM so they need to keep it backward compatible.

I hope this helps you and it's all based on my own experiences. I'm open to correct myself if I'm wrong so help me in the comments.