# Word SaveAs2 error in asp

Tags: ms-word, asp-classic, com

I have a classic asp site that opens a Word document and then saves it as html to be called later. When moved onto a new server (2012 r2) with an updated version of Word (2013) the SaveAs2 no longer works. The error code is -2147023170 and there's no error message. The code looks like:

```
Const WordOpenPathRoot  = "e:\SDA_Root\sourcedocs\"
Const WordPreviewSavePathRoot = "e:\SDA_Root\preview\"

Function UpdateHTML ( theDocRef, theWordPath, theManualDir )
    Const wdFormatHTML = 8
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2

    Dim DocID, EditFileOpenName, EditPDFOpenName, EditFileSaveName, EditPDFSaveName
    Dim WebPublishPath, WebPDFPublishPath, WebPreviewPath, WebPDFPreviewPath
    Dim strHTMLContent, strNewHTML
    Dim strMetaVersion, strMetaDocID, strScriptCode, strStyleSheetCode, strStyleBGCode
    Dim fso, ts 'File System & Text Stream Objects
    Dim tmpstr
    Dim svUserFullName

    svUserFullName  = Session("SesUserFullname")

    EditFileOpenName = trim(WordOpenPathRoot & theWordPath)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(EditFileOpenName) Then

        EditFileSaveName    = trim(WordPreviewSavePathRoot & theDocRef & ".htm")
        WebPreviewPath      = trim(WebPreviewPathRoot & theDocRef & ".htm")

        Set wordApp = CreateObject ("Word.Application")
        Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open ( EditFileOpenName , False, False, False, WordDocPW )

        Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument

        wordDoc.SaveAs2 EditFileSaveName, wdFormatHTML
        wordDoc.Close
        Set wordDoc = Nothing
        wordApp.Quit
        Set wordApp = Nothing
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The code just means "The remote procedure call failed. ( HRESULT 16x800706BE )".

Comment: What line does the error occur at?

Comment: The error occurs on the line wordDoc.SaveAs2 EditFileSaveName, wdFormatHTML

Comment: You **cannot** run Word from a server environment. Redesign your app using a different technology. This is a technical disaster waiting to happen and (depending on who your users are) it *might* even be a violation of your Office license. Word is designed and tested to run in an interactive environment with a human at the console. It will really crash and burn unpredictably in a non-interactive service. See http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757. Also, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665967/2230) is one of the many, many SO answers that already covers this.

Comment: Thanks Euro. In all my searching I hadn't found those articles. I wish I had, it would have saved me many headaches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Office Interop on ASP.net MVC6 website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663123/use-office-interop-on-asp-net-mvc6-website)